# How to use WTForms in Ajax validation?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I accustomed of using WTForms by means of Flask-WTF in my flask application. Doing server side validation is trivial. But how do I leverage this server validation to become a field level, ajax, client side validation? So, when user tab to another input fields, my application can directly goes on validating it and give validation warning/info/error.

I haven't found a resource in the internet yet

Comment: If your app needs to be as secure as possible, there is no such thing as redundancy between server and client side validation code. I usually do it for both.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A possible solution is as follows:

- On the client side you attach a handler to the `blur` event in all the controls in the form.
- Each time the blur event occurs you run a Javascript function that collects the values of all the fields and then submits them as an ajax POST request.
- On the server the view function that handles this ajax POST request instantiates the Flask-WTF form and then validates it. Any errors that resulted from validation are collected into a dictionary that is then sent in a JSON response back to the client.

  For example, a successful validation could return the following JSON:

  ```
  { 
      "errors": {}
  }
  ```

  A response that includes errors could be:

  ```
  {
      "errors": { 
          "name": "This field is required",
          "age": "Enter a numeric value between 0 and 99"
      }
  }
  ```
- The client gets this JSON response and applies the required changes to the DOM to expose the errors.
- If you get a new blur event before the previous one returned you will probably want to abort the pending ajax POST and start a new one with updated field values. You should have only one pending validation request at a time to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Great! Clear answer. Currently I am working on this also, and although the experience is a client side validation, actually it's a server side validation being called by ajax post request. I'll update my question once I finished this task. thanks.

Comment: Just to point out: While this approach keeps the validation code in one place (no need to write redundant code in JavaScript to do real client side validation), it does create a lot of traffic to the server, specially if forms grow large. On each blur a full round trip has to happen in which also the whole Flask/WTForms code has to be run. But as said, to have a real client side validation, one has to write more or less duplicate validation code in JavaScript. Choices...

Comment: @Miguel, Do you have any resources for such implementation? I'm trying to implement this solution in my validation process,

Answer (score 3):

A great question. This is what we do (flask backend, jquery frontend):

- use jquery.forms plugin to ajax forms. Pretty solid mature code. Shortcoming, cannot send json encoded data, only form-urlencoded. Receives plain or json data.
- use wtfroms for form validation. Very mature codebase.
- tried to use wtforms-json for accepting json, very screwy problems.

Comment: I've been considering wtforms-json.  Could you expand on your experience with it?

Comment: Works for me. Pretty transparent, but I do specify concrete version of libraries. Since it patches other libraries, I'd be vary to let the package be updated to the latest...