# real time validation on a wtform. Can I access the validators on the front end?

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms

I have a wtform class which kind of looks like this:

```
class Registration(Form):
  email = StringField('Email', validators=[Required(), Email()])
  username = StringField('Username', validators=[Required()])
  name = StringField('Name', validators=[Required()])
  password = PasswordField('Password',
    validators=[
      Required(),
      EqualTo('confirm_password', message='Your passwords did not match'),
      Length(min=6, max=20, message='passwords must be longer than 6 characters')
    ])
  confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[Required()])
  submit = SubmitField('Register')

  def validate_email(self, field):
    if User.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
      raise ValidationError('Email already registered')

  def validate_username(self, field):
    if User.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first():
      raise ValidationError('Username already exists')
```

I imagine that WTForms does not offer any form of inline validation in real time on the front end, which is fine, but I am wondering if there is a way to make real-time validation by grabbing the validators for fields and using them in some kind of javascript.

For example, the password field. The password must be longer than 6 characters. In this case, I want to show a validation form like so as they are typing it:
[image: what happens when they type in an invalid password]

However, once they type in a password of valid length, it will show this:
[image: they keep typing and make a valid password]

The problem I am having is accessing the requirements and validators of a wtform as it is on the page. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that I use is not completely trivial, but isn't too complicated either. I attach handlers to the change or blur events on the fields I want to validate. When I get this event my handler collects the values for all the fields in the form and submits an ajax POST request to the server. The server now has the entire form and can do validation with WTForms. The JSON response of this Ajax request is the list of validation errors, which the client can display as necessary.

More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19919440/904393).

Comment: hey I'm reading your book right now.

anyway, this was pretty close to what I wanted, changed the blur to a _.debounce so it would work while they're still looking at it inline
Thank you